# which traffic will dominate over the internet link, elastic traffic or inelastic traffic?

Tags: udp, tcp, traffic, network-traffic

Suppose there is a flow of both elastic traffic as well as inelastic traffic over the link (As shown in the Fig).Then which of them will dominate the link (elastic or inelastic).According to me, it should depend upon the flow rate if the inelastic traffic as elastic traffic can then adjust according to it.So can anyone explain this or give an answer to it.
[image: Fig]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself that the inelastic traffic will dominate the link as there is no congestion control as such in the inelastic traffic and it will continue to send the packets irrespective of the congestion whereas the elastic traffic will reduce its sending window as the congestion increases and therefore the inelastic traffic tends to dominate the link.